# images from mysql is loading in location but the are not displayed

Tags: php, mysql, image

```
<?php
    $sql_query="SELECT * FROM tablename";
    $result_set=mysqli_query($con,$sql_query);
    $i=1;
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result_set)) {
    ?>
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img  class="img-responsive" src="path/<?php echo $row[1] ?>" alt="">
        </div>
    <?php
        $i++;  
    }
    ?>
```

The image loads in the location, I checked it using chrome tools. But it dosen't displays the image automatically generated.

```
display: none !important;
```

on img attribute.

Comment: check html source code.right click>view source

Comment: image loads in the location...

Comment: what?can you show related html source

Comment: http://imgur.com/yyzMzW5

Comment: why `display:none` ?

Comment: http://imgur.com/ctpZOhs

Comment: its generating automatically i didnt use

Comment: is image path correct?remove `display:none` first

Comment: edit select statement to select only image row  and change $row[1]  to $row[0]

Comment: hlo there ..i used the same code for other its working there..but y its not working here

Comment: image path is correct..row 0 is image id

Comment: remove this class img-responsive and try to see if every thing ok or not

Comment: not working...same....it automatically generates display none!important

Comment: there is nothing automatically it generate from your css settings, remove every css in your code and try it just html

Comment: not workin bro...gimme youa mail id ill snd d file

Comment: you can edit your post and put every thing here and i'll help you

Comment: @user3595356 Posts should contain all relevant code for future reference, please add it to the post, don't email it to people.

Comment: thanks guys..finally got it...it is due to ad blocker in my machine..got this form http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24808567/image-not-displaying-where-is-style-display-none-coming-from

Comment: try to search `display:none` inside your php file not in css files. maybe you echoed something in there.

Comment: put a semicolon <?php echo $row[1]; ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling adblocker on local machine.. using folder called advert..caused this problem